# Display only last 4 digits in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script, formulas, text-formatting

I have an eight-digit number (`20150613`), I just want to display the last 4 digits like `0613`. I know I can use a formula like `=right(20150613,4)`, but I don't want to do that; I need the number to stay as is, just change how it is displayed.

Comment: can you share a copy of your sheet?

Comment: no I can't. But if you just open up a new sheet and type `20150613` then try your method, you would see `72`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need scripts. Try this on a "copy" of your sheet:

```
function Camouflage(){
  var sh = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  var rng = sh.getRange("A1:A"+sh.getLastRow());
  rng.setNumberFormat("@");
  var val = rng.getValues();
  var rtfArr = val.map(function white(e){
    if (e.map){
      return e.map(white);
    }else{
      var rich = SpreadsheetApp.newRichTextValue(); //new RichText
      rich.setText(e); //Set Text value in e to RichText as base 
      var style = SpreadsheetApp.newTextStyle().setForegroundColor("#ffffff"); // Create a new text style with white foreground
      var buildStyle = style.build(); 
      rich.setTextStyle(0,4,buildStyle); // set this text style to the first four characters
      var rtf = rich.build();
      return rtf;
    }
  });
  rng.setRichTextValues(rtfArr);
  rng.setNumberFormat("0");
}
```

Modify,Debug and learn!!!

Comment: wow. that's insane. I rather just use the `right` function then.

Comment: @jason You could, "but I don't want to do that, I need the number to stay as is... just change how it is displayed.".. Especially-this won't change the underlying number

Comment: @jason So,Did you try?

Comment: no, i'm sure it works. I'm just going to use the `right` function for now, try it later.

Answer (score -1):

This would be possible without script only if your 8 digit number is a date. Then you can custom format it as **`MMDD`**

[image]

Otherwise, the best you can get is to use +1 column with **`=RIGHT(A1; 4)`** and make it visual one while you will be still referring to initial column which will be hidden or in another sheet.